# Css how to get a smooth height transition from 0 to some value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I tried to make each Element of a list appear one after the other. To do this I used css via javascript on each List element i want to manipulate. 
The problem I have now is, even  though the height of the elements is pretty small when they appear it doesnt seem smooth. 
This is my source-code:

```
outercell.style.transition="max-height 2s ease-in";
    outercell.style.maxHeight="125px";
    outercell.style.visibility="visible";
    outercell.style.width="50px";
    outercell.style.marginBottom="4px";
    outercell.style.border="2px solid";
    outercell.style.borderRadius="5px";
    outercell.style.borderColor="#6E6E6E";
    outercell.style.boxShadow="1px 1px 5px #888888";
    outercell.style.padding="3px 25px";
```

I feel like it got something to do with the border,  but I dont really now how to get rid of it.

Every help is appreciated.
Thanks alot ;)

Comment: its obv only the code for one list element. This gets iterated  on  the number of elements with a delay between each iteration.

Comment: Make sure that each item has an initial max-height value of 0, css transition will only transition properly if an initial value is set.

If this doesn't work can you set up a small codepen to demonstrate?

Comment: Tried it and it doesnt seem to  work(well if i didnt do anything wrong).

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJzmeE
If you click on Tuesday 13. element another list unfolds.
Im just taking my first Html css steps so be gentle on me ;D   i know the code is pretty messy

Comment: hm doesnt seem to work right now ill work on that codepen thing

Comment: ok  should  be working  now

Comment: So the problem lies in the padding I set  in my css. So I just set padding-top and padding-bottom to 0px. Thanks for the effort though